Raspberry pi 3B+ ubuntu 20.04 server not opening
I am using raspberry pi 3B+ and I installed ubuntu 20.04 as operating system. I got myself a 3.5inch RPi LCD (A) from Waveshare and ran the following commands
sudo rm -rf LCD-show 

git clone  https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git  

chmod -R 755 LCD-show 

cd LCD-show/

sudo ./LCD35-show

The computer restarted itself and has not opened yet. There was no change in the 3.5 inch screen on it. When I connected the monitor, I received an error that it did not fit certain dimensions.
In the configuration file on the SD card, I turned off the following lines:
dtoverlay=tft35a:rotate=90
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=2

Right now the screen is colorful and there is nothing else. Could this be due to the x11 installation or how can I solve this problem?
